# How to add API Gateway custom authorizers in an AWS SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on some serverless applications and am looking to do all of the deployments using AWS SAM. I'm not finding a lot of information on how to include custom authorizers for my endpoints. There are some (year old) posts that talk about defining them in Swagger (which I'm not using) or Cloudformation.

Does anyone have an example of either of these methods, or know how to define the custom authorizer in the SAM template?

Comment: You are using SAM inside your regular CFN template. You can find out more detail in this documentation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-authorizer.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) now supports defining an `API Auth Object` as a part of the `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource:

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api-auth-object

```
Auth:
  MyLambdaTokenAuth:
    FunctionPayloadType: TOKEN
    FunctionArn: !GetAtt MyAuthFunction.Arn
    Identity:
      Header: Authorization
      ReauthorizeEvery: 300
```

**Original Answer:**

I did eventually get this working using AWS swagger extensions in my template. I have a basic example on my GitHub:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An example serverless "Hello World" application with a custom authorizer.

Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        securityDefinitions:
          test-authorizer:
            type: apiKey
            name: Authorization
            in: header
            x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: custom
            x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
              type: token
              authorizerUri:
                Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${TestAuthorizerFunc.Arn}/invocations
              authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 5
        paths:
          "/":
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: post
                type: aws_proxy
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${HelloWorld.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
              security:
                - test-authorizer: []

  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./HelloWorld
      Events:
        GetApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
                Ref: ApiGateway

  TestAuthorizerFunc:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./TestAuthorizerFunc

  TestAuthorizerFuncPerm:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    DependsOn:
      - ApiGateway
      - TestAuthorizerFunc
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Ref: TestAuthorizerFunc
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

In the API Gateway resource, the YAML of the swagger definition is added under the `DefinitionBody` key. The custom authorizer is defined as:

```
securityDefinitions:
  test-authorizer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: custom
    x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
      type: token
      authorizerUri:
        Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${TestAuthorizerFunc.Arn}/invocations
      authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 5
```

Then the authorizer is attached in the definition for the path that it will secure:

```
paths:
  "/":
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: post
        type: aws_proxy
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${HelloWorld.Arn}/invocations
      responses: {}
      security:
        - test-authorizer: []
```

Code for the Lambda functions can be found here:

https://github.com/brysontyrrell/Serverless-Hello-World/tree/master/hello-world

Answer (score 0):

Looks like authorizer is not supported in the SAM yet based on the discussion here
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/49

Quoting the developer:

> @WilixLead Authorizer is not yet supported natively in SAM. #248 is parent tracking issue for all APIGW features.

I too have hit roadblock today because of this limitation in SAM. I am falling back to traditional cloudforming method.